# Error calling a command based on the number of items within an array

Tags: javascript, api, automation, automated-tests, mocha.js

I have the following problem:
I want to call my service a number of times. This number of times must be based on the number of times in my array.

Below my step by step.
Can someone help me?

**Request**

```
const createClaim = await request()
                .post('/api/payloads')
                .send(payload);
```

**List with to my json request**

```
const pays = async (entryMode) => {
  const payload = {
    card_number_id: '299ddaa0-316c-495e-89bc-65907aaab9a3',
    brand: 'test',
    affiliation_code: gwRegex(/^\d{7}$/),
    card_number_head: gwRegex(/^\d{6}$/),
    card_number_tail: gwRegex(/^\d{4}$/),
    card_scheme: entryMode,
  };
};
```

**List with modes**

```
const entryMode = [
  'manual',
  'manual_with_pass',
  'magnetic_stripe',
  'magnetic_stripe_full',
];
```

Within my test (describe > context > it, I want to create/call the number of times the "payload" const in a way that is created/called once for each item within the entryMode.

```
for (let i = 0; i < entryMode.length; i++) {
  await payload(entryMode[i]);
}
```

That's the summary ...
But I believe that the code has something wrong.
I can't call the pass successfully. Items are not created successfully ...

Someone!?!!?

Thanks guys!!!!

Comment: Where the `payloads` function?

Comment: `Items are not created successfully` where in your code are items created?

Comment: I guess `gwRegex()` is preventing your payload from being created successfully.

Comment: @Chris G I added the request in the body of the text.
But I believe it is a wrong code. Can you shed some light? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @James I added the request in the body of the text.
But I believe it is a wrong code. Can you shed some light? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @tipos I already took it for testing, but without success too ...=/

Comment: The for loop at the bottom calls a `payload` function now, but all is see is a `pays` function that creates a local `payload` object, then simply exits without returning anything. The code is obviously wrong, since `payload` undefined.

Comment: Probably he meant to call `pays()` not `payload()` and it seems like there are more instructions that should run after creating the payload object. I bet problem is payload is not being created, hence the following instructions aren't executed.

Comment: However, if you are trying to run your application with the code above, then it will not work because logic is wrong as Chris pointed out.

Comment: @Chris G Could you give an example more or less focused on the code?
My goal: Call the endpoint, based on the number of items in the entryMode list. That is, there are x items in the list, I will call x the endpoint.
But to call this endpoint, I have a function that has all the JSON to be sent at the endpoint and one of these parameters will use the data from the entryMode list. Understood? Thanks!

Comment: @tipos Could you give an example more or less focused on the code?
My goal: Call the endpoint, based on the number of items in the entryMode list. That is, there are x items in the list, I will call x the endpoint.
But to call this endpoint, I have a function that has all the JSON to be sent at the endpoint and one of these parameters will use the data from the entryMode list. Understood? Thanks!

Comment: Problems.  The function `pays` doesn't do anything, it generates a local variable and does nothing with it.  The for loop calls the function `payload` which you have not shown in your code.  There is nothing here that shows items being created.

Comment: Solutions.  Your question itself is solved by the way you have structured your for loop.  That will work, as long as the code running in your for loop works.  So, the question you have asked is solved by your approach, but the rest of the code needs to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I needed to add a loop.

Comment: It is ok to answer your own question but please add the code you used to answer the problem to help people trying to solve their own problem.